# eyeball comparison

Tags: meaning, phrase-request

Is it correct to use the term "eyeball comparison" to say that two things have been compared by eye?

In the specific case, I am comparing two statistical distributions without doing any quantitative test to compare the two distributions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In math, we might say

> By inspection

So something like

> The two distributions appear to follow the same distribution **by inspection**.

In an informal setting, you might say

> I **eye-balled it** and they look the same.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using 'eyeball comparison', why not use:

> [visual comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_comparison) - **to compare two or more things by eye**. This might be done by placing them side by side; by overlaying them; by alternating an image or by presenting each image to a separate eye.

Answer (score 1):

An "eyeball comparison" is typically meant that something "looks close enough for what we're doing" when no actual measurement was taken since it wasn't needed.

> I "eyeballed" which book on my shelf would help eliminate the wobble in the table.

Does it really matter that the book you chose was 75cm thick vs the one next to it being 82cm? Not really. It's "close enough".

Since you said

> I am comparing two statistical distributions *without doing any
>   quantitative test* to compare the two distributions

That would be the correct term.